# pace.js: "start" event not triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, preload, pace.js

I can't seem to find a solution to this problem I posted in the comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27488146/exclude-elements-from-being-preloaded) 
… I'm using the [pace.js](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/) plugin and I would love to load/show parts of my page immediately without having to wait for the preloader to load all content.

I thought of doing this by simply calling the `start` event and show the selector immediately.

However I can't seem to find the cause why my `done` event is fired, but `start` is not. I also tried with `hide` which is also fired, but `stop` or `restart` is not.

```
$(window).load(function(){

    Pace.on('start', function() { 
        alert('start') // not fired
    });

    Pace.on('done', function() {
        alert('done') // fired!
    });

});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `Pace.start()`, right after event bindings. You then will be able to get the `start` event.

Comment: @matt: Sorry, I have no exp with Pace. Please, create a new question for your current requirement.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to call

```
Pace.restart();
```

if the current page has already loaded with pace progress.

Answer (score 3):

You have to put

```
Pace.on('start', function() { 
   alert('start');
});
```

outside `$(window).load....`
After that it will get start status, You are calling These methods after documentation is loaded so start must be already triggred.

Answer (score 1):

after registering script and css, on your htlm section add this script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onbeforeunload = renderLoading;
        function renderLoading() {
            Pace.stop();
            //Pace.start();
            Pace.bar.render();
        }
```